# mysql where exact match

Tags: mysql, sql

When i write this query

```
SELECT cd.title, cd.city FROM coupon_detail cd WHERE cd.id = 260;
```

return

```
title            city  
---------------  ------
Butterfly world  Mohali
```

and when i write

```
SELECT cd.title, cd.city FROM coupon_detail cd WHERE cd.id = '260abcxyz';
```

return

```
title            city  
---------------  ------
Butterfly world  Mohali
```

see the second one is wrong. i want to get the value only IF ID EXACTLY MATCH ... how to solve this. thanks for your help.

Comment: can you show the complete row? and table definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert the `id` to a string so the comparison will be done exactly. You could use `LIKE` to cause an implicit conversion

```
SELECT cd.title, cd.city FROM coupon_detail cd WHERE cd.id LIKE '260abcxyz';
```

or alternative, you can perform the cast explicitly

```
SELECT cd.title, cd.city FROM coupon_detail cd WHERE CAST(cd.id AS CHAR) = '260abcxyz';
```

However, if all your IDs are integers, it's probably more appropriate to check these values before you try to query the database. (If the ID you're querying with isn't a number, there can't be a match anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because of Type Conversion in MySql. My sql treats '260abcxyz' as an integer in your query and AFAIK because first char is number MySql casts it to a number and it becomes only 260 and that's why you are getting result. If you write character first like 'abcxyz260' it will successes the comparison.

More explanation available here: [Type Conversion in MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html)

As a solution: you should take care that only numbers are passed in comparison and not combination of string and number.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should not use quote if the `id` is `INT`. The way MySQL does is if you use String to compare a INT, it uses just the valid initial integer from start.

see this:

```
mysql> desc coupon_detail;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| title | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> SELECT cd.title, cd.city FROM coupon_detail cd WHERE cd.id = 'ff260';
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT cd.title, cd.city FROM coupon_detail cd WHERE cd.id = '260ff';
+-----------------+--------+
| title           | city   |
+-----------------+--------+
| Butterfly world | Mohali |
+-----------------+--------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT cd.title, cd.city FROM coupon_detail cd WHERE cd.id = 260;
+-----------------+--------+
| title           | city   |
+-----------------+--------+
| Butterfly world | Mohali |
+-----------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT cd.title, cd.city FROM coupon_detail cd WHERE cd.id = 26011;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The idea is not to mix numbers and aphabets to compare a INT column. If you have to you may consider

- converting ID column to VARCHAR. In that case auto-increment may go away.
- have application logic to query only the strings that has numerics.

Answer (score 1):

use like instead = because if the string is too long than exact match won't work in that way
`SELECT cd.title, cd.city FROM coupon_detail cd WHERE cd.id LIKE '260abcxyz';`