# Only initial numbers are being considered when searching for a string

Tags: mysql

This is my Query:

```
select id, name, admin_user_id 
from companies 
where id = "21-09-20181535.abc";
```

Result:

```
21,anand,9331
```

As id column is auto increment, i expect no result as the search string is alphanumeric.
What should i do to get the desired result ?

Comment: update your question and add tha related  data sample and the table schema

Comment: Please check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570884/mysql-where-exact-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit conversion will handle this:

```
select id, name, admin_user_id 
from companies 
where cast(id as char) = "21-09-20181535.abc";
```

This however, won't be using an index on `id`.

Another option is to allow for an implicit conversion using `LIKE` operator **without wildcards**:

```
select id, name, admin_user_id 
from companies 
where id LIKE "21-09-20181535.abc";
```

This is the same as using `=` operator on character types.